# Scraping Java Driven site with Selenium, BS

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I'm fairly new in Python

I am trying to get printer counter value from it's website. The website is in Javascript and i can't scrape nothing out of it.

Site elements look like this and i need the value on highlighted element.

[inspect elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks2LI.jpg)

I have tried using selenium, requests, webdriver ,beautifulsoup.

Tried all webdriver.find methods etc.

My latest code looks like this, i tried bunch of other stuff but got nothing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver


#url = requests.get('http://url')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Chrome/Driver/Path')
url = 'http://url'
get = driver.get(url)

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

print(html)
```

I can scrape nothing out of the webpage, can't get to text box with Xpath, Class, ID or whatever.

I can successfully get elements from other websites but this printer's.

Thanks for help

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual url, and an example of what your desired output should be.

Comment: Url is local so its inaccessible sadly.

Comment: ok. makes sense. Only thing I can think of is what Arran Duff suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the element breadcrumbs in your image, it would appear your content is inside a frame. Each frame is treated by Selenium as a separate document. You need to switch into the frame before you can operate on its content.

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

Above should work if it is the first frame. Then `driver.page_source` and your locators should begin to work.

I explained this in a little more detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335017/cant-select-element-with-selenium-no-matter-what-i-do/54335234#54335234)

Answer (score 0):

What does it print out?

I don't think that, this line will return html text

```
driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

You need to use the page_source attribute to access the html as far as I know...

```
 driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
 html = driver.page_source
```

Comment: neither gives me any of page variables