# Using Selenium in Python to log in to a website

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to login to a website (http://idx.isuzu.jnx.ne.jp:7002/eproc/externalside_logon) using selenium in Python for automation task in my work.
I used the browser.find_element(By.ID, '*USER_ID')... to find the user, pw, and logon button but it didn't work.
I know that we can select the element by name, id, type...could anyone give me an advice?

Thank you.

Advice to find user, pw, logon button by element

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi team, this is the source code:
<td align="LEFT"><input type="text" id="*USER_ID" class="string" name="*USER_ID" size="24" maxlength="12"></td>
<td align="LEFT"><input type="password" id="*PASSWORD" class="string" name="*PASSWORD" size="24" maxlength="12"></td>

Comment: hello team,
I found the solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335017/cant-select-element-with-selenium-no-matter-what-i-do
thank you for your support